# NSDictionary From NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

I was previously using initWithContentsOfURL to download a plist into an NSDictionary, but this hangs the UI when run on the same thread so now I have moved to NSURLConnection the issue is that I can no longer call a method to init the NSDictionary with NSMutableData. What is the best way to take NSMutableData and place it into an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is NSPropertyListSerialization:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:myData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil errorDescription:nil];
```

Is the simpliest option.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I'm going to take a stab at this; even if it doesn't work, I'm sure you can adapt it for your purposes.

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[mutableData bytes] length:[mutableData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmpfile.txt"];
if ([s writeToFile:path atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]) {
    NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

In plain English, create a string from the given data, write that out to a temp file, and then load the temp file into an `NSDictionary` object.

That code is far from perfect (needs stuff like error checking, etc.) but it may get you started.

Caveat: I've been writing Cocoa software for several years, but I've never touched an iPhone, so that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does your NSDictionary have other data that you need to preserve?

In the connection:didReceiveResponse:  method (delegate of NSUrlConnection), you can copy your old NSDictionary into a NSMutableDictionary and then insert the URL response data into it as well. Then convert the NSMutableDictionary into a new NSDictionary.